# Android tablet won't reboot after rebooting using volume and power buttons

Tags: bootloader

I am using a 7" Smartfren tablet called S7.

I was following [this tutorial](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1830108). When I got the last part about the bootloader, I turned my device off. I tried to reboot using the volume buttons and power button, but it won't open up. Also, it cannot be seen by using the command `adb devices`. Thus, I can't use any adb command to access it. What am I doing wrong?

It is recognized by my laptop as Android Bootloader Interface. So, it means that it can still be detected by my laptop, but not when using adb devices in cmd.

**Edit #1:** I tried the fastboot devices command, and it just returned an empty line. I guess it means that nothing happened.

**Edit #2:**
I'll tell you its current status. It can't be normally rebooted, but when you plug it in, it shows that it is charging. Then if I put it back on its case, complete with box and all it heats up meaning it is still functioning and is turned on.

Comment: Use use the `fastboot` command in boot loader mode. Try `fastboot devices`.

Comment: Btw: Best place to ask *this* question is in the XDA thread you've got the tutorial from: at least the one who wrote it (and most likely a dozen others) should be familiar with the procedure.

Comment: Why are you double-posting...[this is the same question but worded differently](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/37874/how-do-you-undo-a-bootloaded-android-device) as if expecting a quick response turn-around time?

Comment: This question has more detail, so the other question should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: I tried asking it over at the forum but until now nobody has answered my pleas for help.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this problem by draining the tabs battery completely. After a day I was able to turn it on using the power button today while charging.