# How do you undo a Bootloaded Android Device?

Tags: bootloader

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android tablet won’t reboot after rebooting using volume and power buttons](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/37855/android-tablet-wont-reboot-after-rebooting-using-volume-and-power-buttons)

I 'think' I have bootloaded my device after pressing the <kbd>Power</kbd>+<kbd>Volume</kbd> buttons simultaneously to reboot it.

Now, it isn't detected by my cmd `adb devices` and `fastboot devices`, this is even though I loaded the 'Android Bootloader Interface' as its driver.

So how do I undo this state?

Comment: Sounds like you entered fastboot mode, Power+Volume buttons enter fastboot mode, try pulling the battery, and wait for a few seconds, then pop in the battery and press power *only*.

Comment: Hey! You posted this [question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/37855/android-tablet-wont-reboot-after-rebooting-using-volume-and-power-buttons) earlier...?

Comment: Yes I did! But I couldn't access that account now! It was unregistered and this one is the one I registered for!

Comment: Are you sure it is fastboot mode? I'll tell you its current status. It can't be normally rebooted, but when you plug it in, it shows that it is charging. Then if I put it back on its case, complete with box and all it heats up meaning it is still functioning and is turned on.

Comment: We seem to have circular duplications :/